# Are these function definitions not the same?

Tags: powershell, autocad, powershell-4.0, autocad-plugin

PowerShell 4.0

It works fine:

```
$cad  = [Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application]
function Get-DocumentManager { $cad::DocumentManager }
function Get-CurrentDocument { $cad::DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument }
function Get-CurrentEditor { (Get-CurrentDocument).Editor }
function Get-CurrentDatabase { (Get-CurrentDocument).Database }
```

All these functions return the necessary objects. But if I rewrite the body of `Get-CurrentDocument` function then I get the problem:

```
$cad  = [Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application]
function Get-DocumentManager { $cad::DocumentManager }
function Get-CurrentDocument { (Get-DocumentManager).MdiActiveDocument }
function Get-CurrentEditor { (Get-CurrentDocument).Editor }
function Get-CurrentDatabase { (Get-CurrentDocument).Database }
```

I get the error message when I launch the `Get-CurrentDocument` function:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Why does it happen? This way works fine for my `Get-CurrentEditor` and `Get-CurrentDatabase` functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible reason for such difference is PowerShell behavior of unrolling collections. If `$cad::DocumentManager` is collection, then `Get-DocumentManager` will return not collection itself, but collection's elements. To prevent this, you need to use unary array operator `,`. It create array with single element. And that array will be unrolled instead of collection.

```
function Get-DocumentManager { ,$cad::DocumentManager }
```